# Ordered array delete operation - big O analysis

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I found this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-insert-and-delete-in-a-sorted-array/) on big O analysis for ordered array operations. The delete operation is categorized as **linear** time in the link.

The actual code performs 2 operations for each input. In the average case, one operation is performed for the binary search to find the value to delete and then a second operation is performed move the rest of the values up after deletion.
The binary search tales logarithmic time and moving values up is linear time, so I would think the average case for runtime analysis would be atleast O(n logn), which loglinear time not linear time.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why would the expressions *multiply*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that when you calculate complexity of 2 operations you don't multiply them. 
Search takes O(log n)
and moving all elements - O(n)
this is O(log(n) **+** n) And, as n > log(n) we say that the complexity is O(n).

You may find more info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorted_array):

Comment: need a bit of clarification on the last sentence = "as n > log(n) we say that the complexity is O(n)." Are you saying that since linear time is always greater than logarithmic time, we should only consider the runtime that has the greatest impact on time and so we can ignore the logarithmic time?

Comment: @sotn exactly, it is because of the rule of summarizing complexities: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum

Answer (score 2):

The search operation and the delete operation are separate operations, each performed once.

Therefore you should add their running times, not multiply them.

Hence you get:

```
O(logN) + O(N) = O(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be `O(n + log(n))` which is `O(n)`.